# Looking for a Google Refresh Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail, nodemailer, refresh-token

I'm developing a Node app for that uses the Gmail API. I know how to use `oauthplayground` to get a temporary refresh token, but I'd like to obtain one that doesn't expire. Is there a way to do that, or is there a different solution that needs to be implemented?

Everything else in the app works exactly like it's supposed to, it's just that the refresh token keeps expiring. When I look online, it says they're not supposed to expire unless they are not used for 6 months, but I can't find any reference that discuss how to actually obtain such tokens. It almost feels like I'm being gaslit.

Answer (score 0):

refresh tokens for apps that are in production do not expire.

[image]

if your app is in testing it will [expire](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) after seven days.

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days, unless the only OAuth scopes requested are a subset of name, email address, and user profile (through the userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, openid scopes, or their OpenID Connect equivalents).

Comment: Does the app need to complete the verification process for this to work, or does the publishing status just need to be "In Production"?

Comment: publishing status of production gives you unlimited refresh token.